# my SQL query is creating new table, How to update existing one instead

Tags: sql, sql-server

My code is :

```
;with cbrand_cte(Particulars, Principal,[SalesAccount]) as
(
    select distinct 
        t2.[Particulars], t1.Principal, t2.[SalesAccount]
    from 
        Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable_Val t2   -- From Product Analysis table for qty
    join 
        Target_Sales_ProductMasterfromSales t1 on t2.Product = t1.product
)
select
    br.Principal, cc.[Particulars], cc.[SalesAccount], br.Product,
    isnull(sls.jan, 0) Jan_Sales_val, isnull(sls.feb, 0) Feb_Sales_val, 
    isnull(sls.mar, 0) Mar_Sales_val, isnull(sls.apr, 0) Apr_Sales_val, 
    isnull(sls.may, 0) May_Sales_val, isnull(sls.jun, 0) Jun_Sales_val, 
    isnull(sls.jul, 0) Jul_Sales_val, isnull(sls.aug, 0) Aug_Sales_val, 
    isnull(sls.sep, 0) Sep_Sales_val, isnull(sls.oct, 0) Oct_Sales_val,
    isnull(sls.nov, 0) Nov_Sales_val, isnull(sls.[dec], 0) Dec_Sales_val
into 
    Target_Sales_MasterTable_Sal_Qty
from 
    cbrand_cte cc
join 
    Target_Sales_ProductMasterfromSales br on cc.Principal = br.Principal
left join 
    Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable_Val sls on cc.[Particulars] = sls.[Particulars]
                                               and br.product = sls.product;
```

Please help with the correct code only updating the existing table which is

```
Target_Sales_ProductMasterfromSales
```

from

```
Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable_Val
```

Currently, I get this error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
> There is already an object named 'Target_Sales_MasterTable_Sal_Qty' in the database.

Comment: The `SELECT .... INTO ....` **only** works if there is **no table yet** with the name defined. In your case, quite obviously, this is **not** the case - so just **don't use** `SELECT .... INTO .... ` anymore and the error will go away.....

Comment: And what do you mean by update? Insert new rows, change existing values?

Comment: Hi I have customer name, Product Name and Product Qty in the table month wise.

now I am going to update Product Value as well against , customer name  product name wise

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **add** additional rows to the existing table, use this syntax instead:

```
;with cbrand_cte(Particulars, Principal, [SalesAccount]) as
(
    .....
)
insert into Target_Sales_MasterTable_Sal_Qty(col1, col2, col3, ..., colN)
    select
        col1, col2, col3, ...., colN
    from 
        .......
```

If you want to **update** existing rows in the target table, you'll need something like this:

```
;with cbrand_cte(Particulars, Principal, [SalesAccount]) as
(
    .....
)
update Target_Sales_MasterTable_Sal_Qty
set col1 = source.Col1,
    col2 = source.Col2, 
    ....,
    colN = source.ColN
from source
where (some condition)
```

Comment: HI I Tried and still, there is an error

```Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
The multi-part identifier "Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable_Val.Jan" could not be bound.```

Comment: ```;with cbrand_cte(Particulars, Principal, [SalesAccount]) as
(
    select distinct t2.[Particulars], t1.Principal,t2.[SalesAccount]
    from PPNL_Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable_Val t2 
    join _Target_Sales_ProductMasterfromSales t1 on t2.Product=t1.product)

update Target_Sales_MasterTable_Sal_Qty
set Jan_Sales_val = Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable_Val.Jan
from cbrand_cte cc
join Target_Sales_ProductMasterfromSales br on cc.Principal=br.Principal
left join Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable_Val sls on cc.[Particulars]=sls.[Particulars] and br.product=sls.product;```